# When does flexbox start wrapping if flex-basis is a percentage

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I used flex: 1 1 calc(33.33% - 2rem) for my items in my flexbox (the 2rem accounts for the column-gap). I realized that it does what I want, by displaying 3 items per row in my flexbox. However, after applying this same property and value in another flexbox, I started to have some questions. I have replicated the same behavior in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ye1mn963/11/)

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 2rem;
}

div {
  flex: 1 1 calc(33.33% - 2rem);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum a est?</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum a est?</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum a est?</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum a est?</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum a est?</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum a est?</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum a est?</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum a est?</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

My question is, when does the flexbox start wrapping? To my understanding, calc(33.33% - 2rem) changes depending on the display size, meaning that as the screen size decreases, the items' size follow suit. So do the items only start to wrap when the text is unable to fit the boxes? From what I've seen, this is the behavior, where the text starts to wrap to the next line as the screen decreases in size, and the items start to wrap to the next line.

Thank you.

Comment: only **one** question per question

Comment: Please rephrase the first question.  I have to read it multiple times to see what you are trying to drive at.